# Query to get the product details added within last week

Tags: mysql, sql

I have written a query to get the count of the products which sold in last week (Monday - Sunday). But the query gives me an error in `GETDATE()` function. Below you can see the error which I get from the SQL

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GETDATE()))AND a.added_date < DATEADD(day, -DATEPART(dw, GETDATE())+1, CONVERT' at line 4
```

Below is the query which is using to get the results

```
SELECT productid, 
       Count(productid)AS COUNT 
FROM   tbl_orderproduct AS a 
WHERE  a.added_date >= Dateadd(day, -Datepart(dw, Getdate()) - 6, 
                              CONVERT(DATE, Getdate())) 
       AND a.added_date < Dateadd(day, -Datepart(dw, Getdate()) + 1, 
                          CONVERT(DATE, Getdate())) 
GROUP  BY productid;
```

Comment: There is no `GETDATE()` function in MySQL. Are you sure that you are using MySQL ?

Comment: You are using the functions that are relevant to MSSQL not MySQL

Comment: Yes I am using MYSQL and by the way, I got that query from one of the answer 
 which is in previous StackOverflow question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
where a.added_date >= current_date - interval 6 day
```

The syntax you have used is for SQL Server, not MySQL.